# Location of php extensions on Linux Server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I know this would be a very stupid question. Recently i have created an Amazon Instance and found php5 is already there. I wanted to establish database connection for which i required odbc extension to be enabled. how can i find ini file because there are many ini fine and all are same. with no .so extension. Please Help

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: One more thing what i am trying to use is to establish ssh2 connection using php. i am not using Apache. will it make any difference? I am using `Linux 3.0.42-0.7-ec2`

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

in your shell, this should print the line from php info that contains the location of php.ini.

Comment: so, did you find php.ini over there?

Comment: Yeah i found but there is no any .so extension enabled!